# "Maior Que" (>) Css

Tags: html, css

Recebi o seguinte trecho de código css do qual me bateu uma dúvida do real significado do "maior que" (>) em css.

```
nav > a{
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

Qual a função dele ali? Qual o nome disso para que eu consiga me aprofundar mais?

Comment: Olá, Lucas. Esse > é algo que chamamos em CSS de combinador. Como ainda estou iniciando na área vou te deixar um link que pode te ajudar a entender melhor. https://www.ti-enxame.com/pt/css/o-que-significa-o-seletor-css-maior-que-o-sinal/969382859/

Comment: @Nilton vale dizer que o artigo linkado diz que "descendente direto" é incorreto, mas na nota de rodapé ele justifica isso usando o termo "filho direto" (óbvio que filho direto é redundante, mas aí ele mudou completamente o contexto). Descendente direto e filho são a mesma coisa e ambos estão corretos, ainda que o nome oficial seja seletor de filho (como já mencionado na postagem linkada no fechamento). Ainda, combinador tem um monte de tipo, não é o `>` o combinador, mas sim um de muitos combinadores.

Comment: @Nilton E só pra constar que esse site que vc indicou é um que faz tradução automática do Stack Overflow em Inglês (ou seja, na minha opinião são apenas parasitas de conteúdo alheio - se a tradução fosse boa, pelo menos...) - Enfim, segue o link da publicação original: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3225891